# Yii2 Авторизация не могу получить свойства User

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня возникла следующая проблема:
При авторизации вызываю метод FindByEmail:

```
public static function findByEmail($email)
{
    return User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();
}
```

из этой функции:

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        var_dump(User::findByEmail($this->email));
        $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->email);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

В принципе все должна быть хорошо, НО на экран выводится следующее:

```
object(app\models\User)#104 (12) {
    ["email"]=>
    NULL
    ["password"]=>
    NULL
["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Василий"
        ["email"]=>
        string(11) "vas@mail.ru"
        ["password"]=>
        string(5) "11111"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(11) "89999999999"
        ["stat"]=>
        int(0)
        ["timestat"]=>
        int(1)
     }
```

Т.е. данные фактически ловятся, НО при обращении

```
Yii::$app->user->email
```

получается NULL, а значение из базы я достать не могу... Уже все перепробовал, Yii::$app->user->identity->email, $user = User::findOne(1) (кстати, также - находит только id и не видит всех остальных свойств), Yii::$app->user->attributes и т.д., но итог все равно один.
Помогите, кто может, пожалуйста, всю голову уже сломал. Заранее спасибо всем неравнодушным!

Answer (score 1):

`Yii::$app->user` это инстанс компонента работы с пользователем. 
Для получения модели пользователя в твоем случае надо обратиться к методу `getIdentity()`.

Данный метод вернет `IdentityInterface`, но объектом будет тот, который указан в конфиге в секции `components.user.identityClass`

```
$user = \Yii::$app->getUser()->getIdentity(); 
echo $user->email;
```